# A couple of questions about relationship with transformer, ELCB/RCCB and MCB

Tags: circuit-design, short-circuit, circuit-protection

[image]

Q1. Which will be the correct way between circuit 1 and 2?

Q2. For circuit 1, the transformer looks like not protected by ELCB and MCB.

1. If short circuit happen after the MCB, the transformer will spoil before the MCB trip?
2. If current leakage to earth before ELCB, the ELCB will not trip. correct?

Q3. For circuit 2, the transformer is protected by ELCB and MCB.

1. If current leakage to earth after the transformer, will the ELCB trip? (Based on my understanding, the transformer already isolate the 110VAC and 230VAC)

Q4. If both circuit are wrong, please advise me the correct way.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Base on my knowledge & experience.

1. Circuit 1.

   - Type of system, suitable for multi-appliance/ multi-load.
   - Before the transformer, usually have capacitor and 'parallel economiser'
2. Circuit 2

   - Type type is common used in constant load appliance

Comment: Which of the OP's questions does this answer, exactly?